# how to get facebook user id or user name with email id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a MVC project where I am trying to get the user id or user name from the facebook by using the email id provided by the user, 
actually i want to fetch the photo of the user, which can be done using

> graph.facebook.com/user_id|user_name/picture

where as i have only have the user email id.
with a little surfing on net i found that user name or user id can be fetched by using

> graph.facebook.com/search?q=emailAddress&type=user&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN

but i was not able to get the access_token.

Also referred
[developer facebook page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#usertokens)
and also [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2)
Any help or direction to work will help indeed.

Basically i understand that i need a access token to get the details.

So how do i do this in my MVC application

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the [Search API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search), **you can only search for Users by name, but not by E-Mail**. It may have been possible in the past, but it is definitely not possible anymore.

Also, for searching by name, you need to use a User Access Token. You only get one by authorizing a User: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

Comment: graph.facebook.com/search?q=emailAddress&type=user&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN  wont work now ??..... but graph.facebook.com/user_id|user_name/picture works fine

Comment: yes? not sure what you are asking now, to be honest.